# View added not getting removed even removeAllViews () is invoked

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am facing problems in removing views even after calling removeAllviews().
Onclick of textView i am adding textView and imageView to layout. Next time when i click textView previously present textview and imageview is not getting removed and is getting appended with th news ones inspite of calling removeAllViews().

Any help is appreciated.

Code is

Activity code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.check);

            content=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
            today=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.today);
            tomorrow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tomorrow);

            today.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {                  

                @Override                 
                public void onClick(View v) {                     
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                    //Toast.makeText(ToDo.this, "Before"+content.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                    content.removeAllViews();                      
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
                    int id=0;                                              
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++) {                             
                        id = idx + 1;                             
                        rel = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.data, null); 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                             
                        params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);                             
                        txt = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.txt);                             
                        txt.setText("AAA"+idx);                              
                        img = (ImageView) rel.findViewById(R.id.img);                             
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub);                             
                        img.setId(id);                              
                        img.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {                                  
                            @Override                                 
                            public void onClick(View v) {                                     
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                     
                                Toast.makeText(ToDo.this,"Selected" + v.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                                }                             
                            });                              
                        content.addView(rel, params);                          
                        }                                           
                    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                     
                    Toast.makeText(ToDo.this, ""+content.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                      
                    }             
                });         

            tomorrow.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {                  

                @Override                 
                public void onClick(View v) {                     
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                    //Toast.makeText(ToDo.this, "Before"+content.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                    content.removeAllViews();                      
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
                    int id=0;                                              
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++) {                             
                        id = idx + 1;                             
                        rel = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.data, null); 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                             
                        params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);                             
                        txt = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.txt);                             
                        txt.setText("Tomo"+idx);                              
                        img = (ImageView) rel.findViewById(R.id.img);                             
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub);                             
                        img.setId(id);                              
                        img.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {                                  
                            @Override                                 
                            public void onClick(View v) {                                     
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                     
                                Toast.makeText(ToDo.this,"Selected" + v.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                                }                             
                            });                              
                        content.addView(rel, params);                          
                        }                                           
                    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                     
                    Toast.makeText(ToDo.this, ""+content.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                      
                    }             
                });         
            }
```

check.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/whiteboard"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Add" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomseperator"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/add"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/add"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topseperator"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Day :"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/day"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/day"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/day"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Today /" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tomorrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/today"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/today"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/today"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Tomorrow /" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tomorrow"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tomorrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tomorrow"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Custom" />

         <ScrollView android:id="@+id/contenntscroll"
             android:layout_width="200dip"
             android:layout_height="200dip"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/whiteboard"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/whiteboard"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/topseperator"
             android:isScrollContainer="false"
             android:scrollbars="none">

              <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
         </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is content here it is specified as linear layout but your newdata.xml has only relative layout once check that

Comment: content is present in main.xml. Code edited

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue but I am not sure,

Inside the **onClickListener of 'today' view**, your logic for **setting the id is wrong**.

try using the following,

```
id = idx + 4; // idx can be 0, 1, 2, 3... and id can be 4, 5, 6, 7...<br/>
```

The logic that you use overrides the id of ImageViews and TextViews which might confuse the OS.

---

If this does not solve the issue, try printing this in the log,

```
Log.d("ChildCount", "content child count:" + content.getChildCount());
```

before the

```
 content.removeAllViews();
```

and update your question with it...